# How Ebean.save(object) work in play framework?

Tags: playframework, ebean

I want to know how Ebean work when we do `Ebean.save()`

```
object obj = new object();

Ebean.save(obj);
```

Comment: What do you observe? Is there something in the docs of ebean or the playframework?

Comment: https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/avaje/ebeaninternal/server/persist/DefaultPersister.java#L382-L389

Comment: Video on cascade statement ordering ... https://youtu.be/RPOaJw8xiJo